# Google Dart Forms working example

Tags: jquery, dart

I'm currently trying to create a simple form in Dart with simply a username and email for registration purposes.

I cannot find a complete ***working*** example that I can test. If someone can explain how to convert the jQuery code below to Dart, I think that would clarify things greatly.

Also I've seen the `FormData` class for Dart but no examples. Any help is appreciated.

```javascript
$("#submit").click( function() {
     $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
             $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
             function(info) {

               $("#responseDiv").empty();
               $("#responseDiv").html(info);
             });

    $("#myForm").submit( function() {
       return false;    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First import the two libraries:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';
```

Then we define a serializer function:

```dart
serializeForm(FormElement form) {
  var data = {};

  // Build data object.
  form.querySelectorAll('input,select').forEach((Element el) {
    if (el is InputElement)
      data[el.name] = el.value;
  });

  return data;
}
```

It simply serializes a form into a `Map` of data. I am not aware of a Dart form serializer, there may be some package for that purpose. Note that the above example only deals with inputs.

Next we assume the following HTML:

```html
<form id="myForm" action="/bar">
  <label>Foo:</label>
  <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" />
</form>

<button id="mySubmit">Send it</button>
```

And last our Dart client-side code for form handling:

```dart
main() {
  FormElement form = querySelector('#myForm');
  ButtonElement button = querySelector('#mySubmit');

  button.onClick.listen((e) {
    var req = new HttpRequest();

    req.onReadyStateChange.listen((ProgressEvent e) {
      if (req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE) {
        print('Data submitted!');
      }
    });

    req.open('POST', form.action);
    req.send(JSON.encode(serializeForm(form)));
  });
}
```

This should get you started.

You might also want to use [Polymer](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/) for your forms.

Comment: A running start. Thank you for such a detailed explanation.

Comment: I've tried to use it, but it seems that many things have changed. For example, `dart:json` is now included in a different way `dart:convert` and the code `form.elements.forEach((Element el) {
    if (el is InputElement)
      data[el.name] = el.value;
  });` gives an error (`There is no such getter 'elements' in 'FormElement'`) I've also noticed that `query(selector)` is now `querySelector(selector)`

Comment: There's still a problem. For some reason `HttpRequestProgressEvent` isn't recognized as a class. They changed the name?

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, it's `ProgressEvent` now :)

Answer (score 0):

Working off the above example. You could do something like this also.

```
    main(){
    var form = new FormData(query('#myForm');
    var button = query('#mySubmit');

     button.onClick.listen((e){
         var request = new HttpRequest();
         request.on.readyStateChange.add((HttpRequestProgressEvent e) {
           if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE) {
             print('Data submitted!');
             }
           });
          request.open('POST','http://localhost/form_info.php');
          request.send(form);
        });
      }
```